# Spring MVC Validator without Message Properties File and Resource Bundle

Tags: spring-mvc

I have scenario like that.

1. I have jsp file, there are 6 fields: userId, userName , lastName, dob, emailId, password.

   ```
   <form:form method="POST"  modelAttribute="keyUserRegistration" action="checkRegistration.do">

   <table width="100%" border="0">

             <tr>
               <td><div class="form-control">
               <form:errors path="userId" ></form:errors>
           <label>
             <p>
               User ID<small class="required"></small>
             </p>  
             <form:input path="userId" id="userId"/>
                </label> </div>
        </td>
     </tr>

     </table>
     </form:form>
   ```

In similar way I wrote all other attributes.

2. I have a Controller to handle request from my page as below:

   ```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/checkRegistration", method = 
      RequestMethod.POST)
      public String submitLogin( @ModelAttribute("keyUserRegistration") 
      UserRegistration userR, BindingResult result, Model model, 
        ) {

   if (userR != null && !userR.equals("null")) {
       registrationValidator.validate(userR, result);
       if (result.hasErrors()) {

           System.out.println("controller result has errors");

           return "registration";
       }
   }
   ```
3. I have Validator class to validate the form:

   ```
      @Component
        public class RegistrationValidator implements Validator{

        public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
              return UserRegistration.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
       }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

   UserRegistration registration = (UserRegistration) target;

   ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "userId", "Please enter User Id");
   ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "emailId", "Please enter Email Id");
   ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "password", "Please enter Password");
   ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "lastName", "Please enter Last Name");
   ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "dob", "Please enter Date Of Birth");
   ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "userName", "Please enter User Name");

     }
   }
   ```

I always meet the Exception:

> org.springframework.context.***NoSuchMessageException***: No message found under code 'Please enter User Id.keyUserRegistration.userId' for ***locale 'en_US'***.

**My question:**

Is there any way of achieving the error messages on jsp using spring validator,but without declaring message properties file and Resource Bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
UserRegistration registration = (UserRegistration) target;
System.out.println(registration.getUserId());
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "userId","error.userId", "Please enter User Id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "userId","error.userId", "Please enter User Id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method-

ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "your attribute","error.your           attribute", "Error message")